# What is the meaning of the word “regenfleckige”?

Tags: translation

I don’t mean to call for help just for translation, but I couldn’t find anything related to this word using Google. Dict.cc usually has many alternatives to choose from, for the meaning of a given word. But in this case there was nothing.

The following sentence is the source of it. I read it in Michael Ende’s *Die unendliche Geschichte.*

> ... war eine regenfleckige Mauer auf der anderen Straßenseite.

The meaning I can glean from the remaining words is:

> … was a wall on the other side of the street.

Does it mean *soaked in rain?*

Comment: Splitting it into `regen` + `fleckige` doesn't help either. The former means `rain` I guess, the latter still escapes me.

Comment: It's an interesing matter, as Michael Ende didn't just use the word "regenfleckig" for his "Die unendliche Geschichte" book, but for his previous children novel "Momo" too. The sentence in which that adjective appears in is: "Statt des alten Hauses mit dem regenfleckigen Verputz...".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not soaked, but *stained* (stain = der Fleck) by rain, whatever that's supposed to mean exactly in this context; visibly wet, would be my guess, perhaps somehow discolored.

Fleck can have a couple of other meanings as well (like patch, or spot) but in this case it refers to a speck or stain of some sort. Ende made that word up on the spot, so you wouldn't find it in a dictionary.

Comment: `Ende made that word up on the spot` he could do that?

Comment: Absolutely. Authors get away with a lot of things, but in German it's very easy (not to mention legal :-) to create new words simply by stringing existing ones together. In English you would say "stained by rain", in German you use "regenfleckig" (literally *rainystained*).

Comment: Actually, it appears that he was not the first to use that word, as a quick search showed, but it's certainly not very common, even though it is perfectly understandable for German native speakers.

Comment: Ende's skill wasn't so much in making up entirely new words, but in subtly redefining them. The *Elfenbeinturm* in this book wasn't the first time that word was used - it was already a fixed phrase (ultimately Biblical) - but after reading *Die Unendliche Geschichte* you might very well think that this instance was the first one, the one that inspired the idiom, and I have no doubt that this was deliberate.

Comment: Be aware that though *Fleck* can translate to *stain,* it always refers to a local stain, which excludes that Ende wanted to just describe that the whole wall was wet. Rather, the use of *fleckig* tells us that the rain caused some visible inhomogeneity on the wall, for example as you sometimes have it shortly after the onset of rain, where some parts of the wall have been hit by raindrops and are visibly wet, while some others haven’t.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It sounds like you're leading towards the literal "rain-flecked" as the translation (a fleck is a small patch of colour, light, dirt or anything like that).

Comment: There is also the adjective *gefleckt* (spotted, patchy) e.g. when describing the fur of an animal.

Comment: @shasank-sawant: You can make up words on the spot in English as well. Normally just as easily as in German, tough sometimes it's a bit more tricky. For example: *rain stained*. The only difference is in spelling. In German you are allowed to spell it as a single word right away. In English it takes decades of usage until the word may be spelled with a hyphen or in a single word. But no matter how it is spelled, it behaves like a single word.

Comment: rainystained would be regnerischfleckig :)

Comment: It's never too late to bring up a typo, is it? I mean, it's only been 5 years ...

Answer (score 13):

Imagine a dry grey wall made of concrete. When you put water on a spot, this spot becomes darker then the rest of the wall. The surface of a soaked wall is fully dark grey. A "regenfleckige" wall has multiple spots which are dark grey, but the rest of the wall (still dry) is in its usual grey. You will only observe this when it starts to rain.

The timeline is:

- dry wall (color: grey)
- "regenfleckige" wall (color: grey with dark grey spots)
- soaked wall (color: dark grey)

Answer (score 3):

"Water stained" would come very close to the intended meaning.